# Reading all files inside a folder with bash

Tags: bash, shell

The problem is to read all files inside a folder and apply certain functions specified in the bash script over each file. Somewhat like calling `map()` in an object in JavaScript, but in this case with bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to loop over the files. Assume your pwd is that folder:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    do your stuff here with "$file" ...
done
```

Comment: I'll try that..The `$f` is the `file` in the loop?

Comment: Ok, i did tat, it works, but only for the first time of the iteration, i have a loop code that is like that:
 `list=$( ls | grep .DAY )
for file in $list do
 echo "The file that i'm working on:"$file
 archiveContent=$( sed -n -e 1p $file)
 COMPRESS_FUNCTION $archiveContent;
done`

well, it works for the first file(I have two files in this folder), in the second `sed` returns to me that the file cannot be read: archive or directory not found, what is that?

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)