# How to recursively replace a string in all files of a folder with the contents of specific file outside the folder using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, replace

### Problem:

- I have a folder (`Essays`) containing many nested sub-directories and "`.txt`" files.
- Only *some* files within this folder contain the string '`[[RepeatedPara]]`' somewhere among the content.
- Outside the folder I have another text file `specialPara.txt` which contains the paragraph that needs to replace `[[RepeatedPara]]` string in all the files.
- I have created a script file "`addPara.sh`" which should first copy the contents of `Essays` into new folder `EssaysCopy` and then perform the replacement of string with contents of `specialPara.txt`.

### Folder Structure

```
.
└── WorkingDir/
    ├── addPara.sh
    ├── specialPara.txt
    ├── EssaysCopy
    └── Essays/
        ├── file-01.txt
        ├── file-02.txt
        ├── file-03.txt
        ├── subDir-01/
        │   ├── file-01-01.txt
        │   ├── file-01-02.txt
        │   └── subSubDir-01-01/
        │       └── file-01-01.txt
        └── subDir-02/
            ├── file-02-01.txt
            └── file-02-02.txt
```

### Script I have so far:

After looking into an answer at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19433747/10400065) I created the following script.

```
#!/bin/sh

cp -r Essays EssaysCopy
cd EssaysCopy
for FILE in $(find *.txt -type f);
do
sed -i -e '/RepeatedPara/{r ../specialPara.txt' -e 'd' -e '}' $FILE
done
```

### Result:

The above script does replace the line containing the string `RepeatedPara` in all files of folder `EssaysCopy` but doesn't process the files within the nested sub-directories.

#### Script I use for creating nested Directories and files for testing:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir Essays
cd Essays
for i in {1..3}
do
mkdir subDir-$i
cd subDir-$i
for j in {1..2}
do
    mkdir subDir-$j
    cd subDir-$j
    for k in {1..2}
    do
        echo "Some Content at the begining" > file-$i-$j-$k.txt
        echo "[[RepeatedPara]]" >> file-$i-$j-$k.txt
        echo "Some Content at the End" >> file-$i-$j-$k.txt
    done
    cd ..
done
for l in {1..2}
do
    echo "Some Content at the begining" > file-$i-$l.txt
    echo "[[RepeatedPara]]" >> file-$i-$l.txt
    echo "Some Content at the End" >> file-$i-$l.txt
done
cd ..
done
for m in {1..2}
do
    echo "Some Content at the begining" > file-$m.txt
    echo "[[RepeatedPara]]" >> file-$m.txt
    echo "Some Content at the End" >> file-$m.txt
done
cd ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a `bash` script, use a `bash` shebang.

Then should use find's `-exec` and quote the glob expression:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp -r Essays EssaysCopy
cd EssaysCopy
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec \
  sed -i -e '/RepeatedPara/{r ../specialPara.txt' -e 'd' -e '}' {} \;
```

assuming, as you mentioned that your `sed` command works as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Works as expected! I assume the backslash after ```-exec``` and at the end (before ;) is just for formatting the code on newline? or is it required to surround the command to be executed with ```\<command>\```?

Comment: The last one to escape the `;` is required. You can remove the other one and the newline though.

Comment: replacing `\;` with `+` should work too, and would come with performance gains